# How to use DayOfWeek with Spring, JPA and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I want to store a DayOfWeek in my PostgreSQL database. Therefore Im using a converter to store it as an Integer. But Im open to store it as other datatypes if you have better suggestions. 
The converting does not take place, as im not seeing the error prints i added. The error message strengthes this.
Do I have to change my crudrepository or where is my mistake?
My Entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "opening_hours")
public class OpeningHours {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "day")
    @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekIntegerConverter.class)
    private DayOfWeek day;
```

The CrudRepository Im using looks like that:

```
public interface OpeningHoursRepository extends CrudRepository<OpeningHours, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT closing_time FROM opening_hours WHERE day = :day_of_week", nativeQuery = true)
    LocalTime getShopClosingTimeOn(@Param("day_of_week") DayOfWeek dayOfWeek);
```

For storing the DayOfWeek I use the following converter:

```
@Converter // I tried (autoapply=true) already but did not change anything
public class DayOfWeekIntegerConverter implements AttributeConverter<DayOfWeek, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(DayOfWeek attribute) {
        System.err.println("converting dayofweek to int");
        return attribute.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        System.err.println("converting int to dayofweek ");
        return DayOfWeek.of(dbData);
    }
}
```

My database table looks the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS opening_hours
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    day INT
);
```

Here is the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
...
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea
  Hinweis: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 51
```

Comment: Could you provide us an error message or something else showing us the problem you get ?

Comment: added the error message. 
Saving it as a date is no option because im only interested in the day of the week. Dont want to deal with any specific dates

Comment: modified my answer @juuubbb

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in modified answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your converter.
The main problem is your query on the repository. I have changed it in my local environment and it works like a charm.

**I used JQL instead on native query**

below is my code

```
public interface OpeningHoursRepository extends CrudRepository<OpeningHours, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT closingTime FROM OpeningHours WHERE day = :day_of_week")
    public LocalTime getShopClosingTimeOn(@Param("day_of_week") DayOfWeek dayOfWeek);

}
```

I have assumed a variable **closingTime** as your code in post doesn't have it

```
public class OpeningHours {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    private LocalTime closingTime;

    @Column(name = "day")
    @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekIntegerConverter.class)
    private DayOfWeek day;
}
```

**Edit:**

> **In case you want to stick to native query**

Then you should write your repository as below

```
public interface OpeningHoursRepository extends CrudRepository<OpeningHours, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT closing_time FROM opening_hours WHERE day = :#{#day_of_week.getValue()}", nativeQuery = true)
    public LocalTime getShopClosingTimeOn(@Param("day_of_week") DayOfWeek dayOfWeek);

     }
```

Comment: nextval('shaileshtest.opening_hours_id_seq'::regclass) whats this?
I think the bigger problem is that the conversion is not working

Comment: modified the answer as per discussion

Comment: nice to know :) , please accept the answer if it's working for you @juuubbb

Comment: sorry i did it now. Upvoting doesnt work because my account is relatively new..
What exactly is the syntax behind this #{#?

Comment: no worries for upvoting, an accepted answer is enough as it increases the credibility of the answer

Comment: Just to be clear: the #{#...} is a notation of JPA which allows you to call methods from your java objects?

Comment: I don't have precise words to explain this but this is SpEL(spring expression language), your query needed a value from  dayOfWeek  object, so spSpEL helped to call method getValue from dayOfWeek,  inside your query

Comment: @juuubbb , This will help you to understand https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Answer (score 0):

The Converter Class works in the `Entity` because of the `@Convert` annotation but in the repository there is nothing for JPA to convert the DayOfWeek parameter to an Integer inside the native query.

The better solution is to write JPQL query so JPA will use the `OpeningHours` class and it will see that the `DayOfWeek` parameter is matching the `day` attribute and it will do the conversion.

Comment: So for your solution I just have to remove the "nativeQuery = true"?
Because this leads to the exception, that the table opening_hours is not mapped..

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.time.LocalTime backend.dataaccess.OpeningHoursRepository.getShopClosingTimeOn(java.time.DayOfWeek)!
...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: opening_hours is not mapped [SELECT closing_time FROM opening_hours WHERE day = :day_of_week]
`

Comment: I have tested you code,in case you want minimum change either change the dayofwek in repository as integer,  or change query to day = :#{#day_of_week.getValue()}"

Comment: this is working, thank you so much @ShaileshChandra